# Convert x-illion into standard form

Tags: code-golf, math, number, kolmogorov-complexity

Given a string, consisting of a prefix and then "illion", convert this number into standard form.

For example:

```
"million" -> 10^6
"trillion" -> 10^12
"quattuordecillion" -> 10^45
```

The program needs to be able to handle input going up to Centillion, which is 10^303. A  list of names and their standard form values can be found [here](http://polytope.net/hedrondude/illion.htm) - note that this gives values for every 10^3 increment up to 10^63, but then gives them in 10^30 increments, however the pattern is fairly straightforward.

The program needs to handle all 100 cases (even the ones not explicitly given by the website provided) - here are some examples of this:

```
"sexvigintillion" -> 10^81
"unnonagintillion" -> 10^276
"octotrigintillion" -> 10^117
```

Input can be given via STDIN, function argument or hard-coded as a string.

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: What would 10^70 be?

Comment: 10^70 doesn't have a representation because 3 isn't a factor of 70 - but 10^69 would be sexvigintillion. 10^70 would be 10 sexvigintillion.

Comment: Actually, doevigintillion = 10^69, and sexvigintillion = 10^81.

Comment: @Remy I would guess that you use the long scale (if that's right)? It sounds like this question uses the short scale.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: The question's provided list of names says vigintillion = 10^63, and shows that un- adds 3 to the power, doe- adds 6, sex- adds 18, etc.

Comment: @Remy You are absolutely right, apologies.

Comment: Besides, in the long scale, one vigintillion would be 10^120.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2 (<s>384</s> <s>368</s> <s>365</s> <s>348</s> 347 bytes)

```
def c(s):
 s=s[:-6].replace('int','');k=0;d=dict(un=1,doe=2,tre=3,quattuor=4,quin=5,sex=6,septen=7,octo=8,novem=9,b=3,tr=4,quadr=5,qu=6,sext=7,sept=8,oct=9,non=10,dec=11,vig=21,trig=31,quadrag=41,quinquag=51,sexag=61,septuag=71,octog=81,nonag=91,cent=101)
 for p in(s!='m')*list(d)*2:
    if s.endswith(p):s=s[:-len(p)];k+=3*d[p]
 return 10**(k or 6)
```

(The `if` line is indented with a single tab, and the rest with single spaces.)

Here `c('million') == 10**6` has to be a special case because `'novem'` also ends in `'m'`.

Examples:

```
c('million') == 10**6
c('trillion') == 10**12
c('quattuordecillion') == 10**45
c('novemnonagintillion') == 10**300
c('centillion') == 10**303
```

Thanks to Falko for obfuscating it down to 350 bytes.

---

For practice I tried rewriting this as a one-liner using lambdas. It's <s>404</s> <s>398</s> <s>390</s> <s>384</s> <s>380</s> 379 bytes:

```
c=lambda s:(lambda t=[s[:-5].replace('gint',''),0],**d:([t.__setslice__(0,2,[t[0][:-len(p)],t[1]+3*d[p]])for p in 2*list(d)if t[0].endswith(p)],10**t[1])[1])(un=1,doe=2,tre=3,quattuor=4,quin=5,sex=6,septen=7,octo=8,novem=9,mi=2,bi=3,tri=4,quadri=5,qui=6,sexti=7,septi=8,octi=9,noni=10,deci=11,vii=21,trii=31,quadrai=41,quinquai=51,sexai=61,septuai=71,octoi=81,nonai=91,centi=101)
```

Comment: +1 for abusing OP's lack of specification of whether "10^x" should be *printed* or whether just returning the numerical value is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, although `return'10^'+str(3*k)` would only be 4 bytes more.

Comment: Since this is python 2, you could use a space indent for the first level, and tab for the second. You can also move both `a` and `b` into the function as keyword arguments.

Comment: `1000**k` is shorter than `10**(3*k)`. Incrementing `k` by `3*d[p]` is also equally short.

Comment: You can save a few characters by avoiding the early exit using `if'm'==s:k=6;d=[]` instead of a second lengthy `return` statement.

Comment: Two more bytes: `if(s!='m')*s.endswith(p)` and `return 10**[k,6][k<1]` saves you the other `if` statement. That's it for tonight. :)

Answer (score 9):

### JS (ES6), <s>292</s> 270

Understands only the numbers written in the given list. The OP isn't clear about the others.

```
z=b=>{a="M0B0Tr0Quadr0Quint0Sext0Sept0Oct0Non0Dec0Undec0Doedec0Tredec0Quattuordec0Quindec0Sexdec0Septendec0Octodec0Novemdec0Vigint0Trigint0Quadragint0Quinquagint0Sexagint0Septuagint0Octogint0Nonagint0Cent".split(0);for(i in a)if(~b.indexOf(a[i]))return"10^"+(20>i?3*i+6:93+30*(i-20))}
```

Example:

```
z("Billion") // "10^9"
z("Centillion") // "10^303"
```

Comment: You can remove the zeroes in the string and replace `split(0)` with `match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g)` to use regexes to match each string.

Comment: This only handles the "un, doe, tre, etc" prefixes for decillion. It should also handle cases like unvigintillion = 10^66 and novemnonagintillion = 10^300

Comment: You can shorten this by using ES6 functions `=>`.

Comment: thanks for the tips. @Remy are you sure? the OP doesn't seem to ask that

Comment: Seems clear to me that all multiples of 3 are required: "... this gives values for every 10^3 increment up to 10^63, but then gives them in 10^30 increments, however the pattern is fairly straightforward" in the OP. Also OP gives an example of "sexvigintillion" in a comment.

Comment: I thought I had made it pretty clear in my question description - see the "note" part after I give the link - however I will clarify.

Answer (score 9):

## C, 235

Handles all 100 cases.
Program uses stdin and stdout.

Who needs regexes for camel-case splitting?

```
char*Z="UUUi+W<)E(<7-7-++*)('&%$,*$&%$",u[999]="\0MBRilDriPtiNiUnOeReTtUiXTeCtVeCiGRigRaUagInquiXaXsexPtuOgOoNaCeCeK1",s[99],*U=u+67;
main(n){
for(gets(s);*--U;)
*U<95?
*U|=32,
n+=!!strstr(s,U)*(*Z++-35),
*U=0:
3;puts(memset(u+68,48,3*n)-1);
}
```

#### Example

```
octoseptuagintillion
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: This thing doesn't even look like C anymore... I'm amazed.

Comment: Why the space (`*U<95 ?`) and all the newlines?

Comment: @tomsmeding The space was an oversight. The newlines make the code "readable" and are not included in the count.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <strike>381</strike> 377 bytes

```
(defn c[x](let[l{"M"6"B"9"Tr"12"Quadr"15"Quint"18"Sext"21"Sept"24"Oct"27"Non"30"Dec"33"Undec"36"Doedec"39"Tredec"42"Quattuordec"45"Quindec"48"Sexdec"51"Septendec"54"Octodec"57"Novemdec"60"Vigint"63"Trigint"93"Googol"100"Quadragint"123"Quinquagint"153"Sexagint"183"Septuagint"213"Octogint"243"Nonagint"273"Cent"303}v(l(clojure.string/replace x #"illion$" ""))](Math/pow 10 v)))
```

Example:

`(c "Septuagintillion") ;; 1.0E213`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 204 bytes (+9 for formatted String)

```haskell
import Data.List
x s=10^(f$[a|k<-tails s,i<-inits k,(b,a)<-zip["ce","ad","un","do","b","mi","vi","tr","at","ui","x","p","oc","no","ec","g"]$100:4:1:2:2:[1..],b==i])
f[]=3
f(x:11:r)=30*x+f r
f(x:r)=3*x+f r
```

In GHCi:

```
*Main> x "decillion"
1000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Replacing `10^(` with `"10^"++(show.` adds another 9 bytes:

```haskell
import Data.List
x s="10^"++(show.f$[a|k<-tails s,i<-inits k,(b,a)<-zip["ce","ad","un","do","b","mi","vi","tr","at","ui","x","p","oc","no","ec","g"]$100:4:1:2:2:[1..],b==i])
f[]=3
f(x:11:r)=30*x+f r
f(x:r)=3*x+f r
```

In GHCi:

```
*Main> x "decillion"
"10^33"
```

**Edit:** I had to correct for `"quinquagintillion"` which contains `"qua"`.